# How to check if particluar view is pressed for more than a 2 second

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

Hi i need to chceck wheather any view is clicked for more than 2 sec any code , snippet , tutorial will help.

Answer (score 7):

You'll want to use [`UILongPressGestureRecognizer`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UILongPressGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and read the [Event Handling Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/GestureRecognizers/GestureRecognizers.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH6-SW1).

Comment: A snippet won't help you if you don't understand the principles behind gesture recognizers. They're a different mechanism from the event responder chain and they have some differences in behavior. Anyway, if you read the guide you'll see plenty of applicable sample code.